# Solution to this specific differential equation $y'=f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove or disprove:

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Then the initial value problem
> $y'=f(y)$ with $y(0)=1$ always has a solution $y\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Now, I think the crucial point is what we do with functions $f(y)$, which have roots. For all other functions, separation will work. Even for $f(y)=0$, we can just take $y=0$. Unfortunately, I dont know how to prove or disprove this.

Comment: It isn't true that a solution will be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, e.g. $f(y)=1+y^2$, $y=\tan(x+\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Extendability of solutions to the whole real line is not guaranteed even if $f$ satisfies the hypothesis of Cauchy-Lispchitz: namely, the one and only maximal solution to $$\begin{cases} y'=y^2\\ y(0)=1\end{cases}$$
is $y:(-\infty,1)\to\Bbb R,\quad y(t)=(1-t)^{-1}$.

Existence of solutions defined on some neighbourhood of $0$ is guaranteed by [Peano's existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem). Since differentiable functions need not be locally Lipschitz, I don't think differentiability of $f$ can play a role in distinguishing this case from the general one, but I have been wrong before (in fact, I can't quite think right now of an example where $f$ is differentiable and the ODE has more than one solution).